# How do I remove strong tags & inline styling from headings?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, inline, html-heading

I'm trying to get rid of inline styling and strong tags within headings in wordpress. e.g. `<h2 style="font-size: 18px"><strong>This is </strong><strong>mess</strong><strong>y</strong></h2>`

1. Would I be able to use a regex replace to get rid of the tags without losing the text in between the tags?
2. Would you recommend to use the function.php to filter the tags or should I export the entire wp_posts table and do a regex replace in sublime?

Comment: what about php `strip_tags()` function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: I would recommend to use a function inside `function.php`. It will work everytime you add anything to your web site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str='before <h2 style="font-size: 18px"><strong>This is </strong><strong>mess</strong><strong>y</strong></h2>after';

$pos = strpos($str, "<h2");
$pos2 = strpos($str, "</h2>");

$partstr = substr($str, $pos, $pos2);
$tag = substr($str, $pos, 3);

$partstr2 = str_replace("<strong>" , "", $partstr);
$partstr2 = str_replace("</strong>" , "", $partstr2);
$partstr2 = str_replace('<h2 style="font-size: 18px">', "", $partstr2);


$newstr = str_replace($partstr, $tag . ">".$partstr2 , $str);

echo  $newstr;
```

I would not recommend preg_replace.

Edited code.
Working example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/13be2bfb61de6e7d3591caf9a343011a771bab63

Comment: what about inline styles? btw you can pass an array of strings to search for in `str_replace()`

Comment: @billyonecan I guess you could do the same for that.

Comment: This would replace all `<strong>` tags, correct? I'm trying to filter only the ones within h2-h6 headings.

Comment: @Jonas I think I would have solved it then with strpos() to find the start H tag and end H tag and only str_replace that part and then rebuild the string with the new contents

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, looks great. And this would work for wordpress posts with multiple h2 headings?

Comment: @Andreas, sorry gotta ask again. Would the snippet that I add to the functions.php look something like this? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/386e7b7d0e6e19541e100c13f1835afa30e434ae

Comment: @Jonas I have never used wordpress or functions.php, so I don't know. But it looks correct. You can replace the 2 in the find string with a variable and it will work on more than h2

Comment: @Jonas if the answer was correct you should use the accept answer button, it marks the question as correctly answerd and nobody needs to look at this question to see if it's done or not